# My Macbook can connect to ethernet over Ubuntu but not OS X

Tags: macos, ethernet

I'm currently dual booting Ubuntu 14.04 and OS X Mavericks (10.9.4) on my 2014 Macbook Pro. When running Ubuntu, I can plug in the Ethernet cable and instantly be connected. But when running OS X, there's no Ethernet connection detected.

Since I was able to connect on Ubuntu instantly, I shouldn't have the issue of having to set up additional configurations, such as a PPoE connection. Since I'm dual booting I'm obviously also using the same laptop, the same Ethernet cable, and the same Ethernet port so it doesn't seem like there should be a hardware issue either.

What could be the issue here?

[image]

When I run "ifconfig" in my terminal while booting OS X, this is what I get:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 80:e6:50:16:b0:c0 
    inet6 fe80::82e6:50ff:fe16:b0c0%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet 192.168.70.245 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.70.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 72:00:05:04:94:20 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 72:00:05:04:94:21 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 82:e6:50:61:cb:00 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 02:e6:50:16:b0:c0 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
```

After reinstalling OS X [I can no longer see the rEFInd screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518221/reinstalled-os-x-refind-doesnt-boot-anymore-and-goes-straight-to-os-x) and thus cannot boot Ubuntu. However, I remember when I ran "ifconfig" earlier I saw an item that started with "eth0"

Comment: sounds like the Ubuntu is keeping the Ethernet to it self and not letting OSX have it. Check in Terminal for active connections.

Comment: When you click on the **+** button, you should be presented with a drop down menu with a list of interfaces. Can you post a screen shot of this menu? Can you also run `ifconfig` in a terminal and **Application > Utilities > System Information** and look at **Hardware > Ethernet Cards** and tell us what they display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue was with my Ethernet adapter, which is incompatible with OS X Mavericks. I just checked out its one-star reviews here: [http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Adapter/product-reviews/B0095EFXMC/ref=cm_cr_dp_qt_hist_one?ie=UTF8&filterBy=addOneStar&showViewpoints=0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0095EFXMC)

Answer (score 1):

If you can see the interface in `/Utilities/System Configration` > "Ethernet Cards", try [creating a new network location](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5289).

If the issue persists in a new location, you can reset OS X's detected network interfaces by (re)moving `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist`.  If you want to play it absolutely safe, you could (re)move the entire `SystemConfiguration` folder, but this will affect other settings (like custom network authentication, power management settings, etc.). ***NOTE***: this step supersedes testing it in a new user since it removes global preferences (which affect every user).

If you're still not seeing it, try [booting to your Recovery Partition](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718), launching Terminal, and running `ifconfig` to see if the Recovery partition can see the network interface.  If the Recovery Partition sees it, a reinstall of OS X might be needed.  If it doesn't, well then you did something that I've never seen... :)

Comment: Creating a new network location didn't change anything, nor did deleting the entire SystemConfiguration folder. I booted to my Recovery Partition, ran "ifconfig", but didn't see an ethernet connection.

Comment: Also, even though I didn't see an ethernet connection, I reinstalled OS X anyways, hoping it would help. Now, when I restart my laptop I don't see the rEFInd screen and I get taken straight to OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You deleted your Ethernet connection.  From System Preferences -> Network, hit the '+' and add a new one (it may be Thunderbolt or Thunderbolt Bridge).

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't look like it changed anything- http://i.imgur.com/Nu7hZ6B.png

Comment: Hit apply, disconnect and reconnect the Ethernet. Are you using thunderbolt or is it an actual Ethernet port?

Comment: Just tried that, but it doesn't look like anything changed. I'm using an actual Ethernet port.

Comment: Create a new user and see if the problem persists?